# How to change tickbox color in custom checkboxes in css?

Tags: html, css

I have been working for some functionality in checkboxes, but this makes me bit confused when changing the styles of checkbox.

I tried setting the color to the checkbox after clicked, but not worked.

```
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
    display: block;
    color: #000 !important; 
}
```

This seems to be bit easy, but somehow the tickbox color (white) cannot be changed. Can someone help me out?

Here's the code snippet.

```css
.container {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 35px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 22px;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

/* Hide the browser's default checkbox */
.container input {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Create a custom checkbox */
.checkmark {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    background-color: #eee;
}

/* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */
.container:hover input ~ .checkmark {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

/* When the checkbox is checked, add a blue background */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark {
    background-color: #2196F3;
}

/* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */
.checkmark:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}

/* Show the checkmark when checked */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
    display: block;
    color: #000 !important; 
}

/* Style the checkmark/indicator */
.container .checkmark:after {
    left: 9px;
    top: 5px;
    width: 5px;
    height: 10px;
    border: solid white;
    border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<label class="container">One
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container">Two
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container">Three
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container">Four
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The checkmark is being created using a border color, here:

```
.container .checkmark:after {
    border: solid white;
}
```

So just change that color as desired:

```css
.container {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 35px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 22px;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

/* Hide the browser's default checkbox */
.container input {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Create a custom checkbox */
.checkmark {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    background-color: #eee;
}

/* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */
.container:hover input ~ .checkmark {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

/* When the checkbox is checked, add a blue background */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark {
    background-color: #2196F3;
}

/* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */
.checkmark:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}

/* Show the checkmark when checked */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
    display: block;
}

/* Style the checkmark/indicator */
.container .checkmark:after {
    left: 9px;
    top: 5px;
    width: 5px;
    height: 10px;
    border: solid #000;
    border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<label class="container">One
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container">Two
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container">Three
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container">Four
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Daniel  :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to change the colour of the tick, you have to change the border colour.

```
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
    display: block;
    border-color: #000; 
}
```

```css
.container {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 35px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 22px;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

/* Hide the browser's default checkbox */
.container input {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Create a custom checkbox */
.checkmark {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    background-color: #eee;
}

/* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */
.container:hover input ~ .checkmark {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

/* When the checkbox is checked, add a blue background */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark {
    background-color: #2196F3;
}

/* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */
.checkmark:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}

/* Show the checkmark when checked */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
    display: block;
    border-color: #000; 
}

/* Style the checkmark/indicator */
.container .checkmark:after {
    left: 9px;
    top: 5px;
    width: 5px;
    height: 10px;
    border: solid white;
    border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<label class="container">One
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container">Two
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container">Three
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container">Four
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
```

Comment: This still sets the border as white then overrides it as black -- mostly harmless, but it's unnecessary to have both rules...

Comment: Thanks for your help Musa :)